# JS and checkbox: multiple choice

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I'm developing this [website](http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/wohnungen.html) where I have a table in this page with some filter choices.

What I need, if it is possible, is to make multiple choices, for example to select one checkbox from here...

```
<form class="filter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="zimmer5" class="unchecked"> 5.5
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="zimmer4" class="unchecked"> 4.5
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="zimmer3" class="unchecked"> 3.5
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="zimmer2" class="unchecked"> 2.5
    <br>
</form>
```

...and another one from here...

```
<form class="filter">
    <input type="checkbox" id="range1" class="unchecked"> 1200 – 1600
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="range2" class="unchecked"> 1600 – 2000
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="range3" class="unchecked"> 2000 – 2400
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="range4" class="unchecked"> 2400 – 3000
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="range5" class="unchecked"> 3000 – 3400
</form>
```

...and then display results, for example, with Zimmer 4.5 that has also a "range" 2000 - 2400 or 2400 - 3000

I think I have to change something in this script, right?

```
$('input.unchecked').on('change', function() {
    $('input.unchecked').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: all id(s) should be unique , attribute name can be same

Comment: @user2181397 i edited the first post, i think that i have to change something in that script

Comment: How about just using a radiobutton for the single choice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your js so it changes only the inputs within the same form. E.g.:

```
$('input.unchecked').on('change', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('input.unchecked').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the support. But for example How can i filter the results when i use this script? For example i need that when you click on Zimmer 4.5 and then on Haus 1 you can display ONLY rows with Zimmer 4.5 and Haus 1.

I need a new script for this?

Comment: @PicaLesu In order to accomplish that you could add different classes to your forms. E.g. `<form class="filter decimal-numbers-filter">` and later refer to the checked item as `$('.filter.decimal-numbers-filter input:checked')`.